# Can we add chat oneboxing support for arXiv preprints?

Tags: feature-request, chat, onebox

SE chat has a support for oneboxing non-SE links like Wikipedia,

[image: Screenshot of oneboxed Wikipedia link in chat]

I was hoping that this support could be extended to  [arXiv](http://arxiv.org/).

For those that are not familiar with arXiv, it is a website/service that hosts pre-print editions of articles in Physics, Mathematics, Computer Science, Quantitative Biology, Quantitative Finance and Statistics. I am occasionally linking to arXiv preprints into chat when I find particularly interesting articles  (e.g., [The Nature of Scientific Proof in the Age of Simulations](http://arxiv.org/abs/1404.6248)) or when someone is asking about a particular research topic.

**Is it possible to have arXiv articles oneboxed in chat?**

For example, I would think that the Title, author, & abstract should be pulled in for the preview:

[image: Mockup of arXiv onebox]

Note that the X image on the left is taken from [the Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.commonsware.android.arXiv).

Comment: It might be good if we had a tentative design for the preview, showing the data we want to be shown.

Comment: Man, that'd be really great. I'm linking to arxiv articles all the time in chat.

Comment: I personally find the [iOS app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/arxiv/id302515757?mt=8)'s color scheme a bit less... sinister. Strange that the arxiv itself doesn't seem to have any concise logo.

Comment: Another meta question about arXiv.org: [Trackbacks from SE to the arXiv.org?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240520)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've made a 'plugin' for this to be used with my [custom onebox userscript at Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/q/6642/26088). It uses the arXiv API to get the title, author and abstract. The logo is from the Android app.

The end onebox:

> [image]

It works for both links to the PDFs or just the abstract page

#### You can install the custom onebox userscript from [GitHub](https://github.com/shu8/SE-Chat-Custom-Oneboxes/raw/master/custom-oneboxes.user.js)

All you need to do then is paste the below code (or 'plugin') at the top of the file, before the `--------------------------------------------------------`

```
customSites['arxiv.org'] = function(link, $obj) {
    $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/shu8/SE-Chat-Custom-Oneboxes/master/arxiv.css">');
    var id = link.split('/')[4];
    if (id.indexOf('pdf') > -1) {
        id = id.replace('.pdf', '');
    }
    $.get("http://export.arxiv.org/api/query?search_query="+id, function(d) {
        var $xml = $(d);
        console.log($xml);
        var title = $xml.find('entry title').text();
        var author = $xml.find('entry author').text();
        var summary = $xml.find('entry summary').text();
        var url = $xml.find('entry link[type="text/html"]');
        
        var template = "<div class='arxiv-container'> \
                            <img src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/0h65A.jpg' /> \
                            <div class='title'><a href='"+url+"'>"+title+"</a></div> \
                            <div class='author'>"+author+"</div> \
                            <div class='desc'>"+summary+"</div> \
                        </div>";
        $obj.html(template);
    });    
};
```

This would, of course, be best if implemented by SE themselves because then it doesn't require extra installation, but I think it'll do for now! ;)